# How are large css style files are developed and maintained?

Tags: css

I frequently see large css files used by complicated websites. The file size can be hundreds of kb. It isn't easy to understand such large files.

How are they developed and maintained? Do the developer directly work with these large files or are they some tools to manage complexity to make the files more understandable by developers and maintainers?

Comment: Doesn't deserve a new answer, but noting: nowadays, also, frontend frameworks tends to be favored by some developers over CSS, for example Tailwind is hot right now.

Comment: But css is still the basis of such frameworks? If I want to tailor the CSS of an existing webpage to simplify the style, how can I understand the CSS so that I can do so?

Answer (score 1):

Usually some sort of CSS minification is used to combine several CSS files into one giant one, while at the same time, reducing whitespace to shrink the file size.

Also using technologies such as SASS or LESS files allows you to set variables and "mix-ins" to simplify and standardize several CSS files.

For example, you might have a LESS file which defines a "main color" variable, and instead of hard-coding that color into several classes, you only reference the original variable for the color. If you decide to change the color later, you can change it in one place.

There's a million references on the interwebs talking about these file types.

Comment: Keep in mind that these variables, mix-ins and extends are only in the precompiled code, in the compiled code, they're repeated every where that they are used.